# Printing a Python List Vertically in Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

This is probably a stupid question. I have scoured the forums here for a solution, but I cannot seem to implement it here within my code. I have attempted a .join method as well as + '\n' with absolutely no luck. If it goes well, nothing changes, and worse, it completely breaks. The code in question is below. The goal is to get the final print out in the text file to be vertical, not horizontal and jumbled together. Thank you all in advance. I also have similar code that I have successfully gotten to print out the way I wanted, but I cannot seem to replicate that here. Would be happy to provide if need be, but it is simply with print statements outside of the for loop, and the loop calls the loop variable to print. Pretty easy setup there.

```
import ipaddress  
import random 
import os

os.chdir('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Desktop/')

network = ipaddress.ip_network('192.0.7.0/24')
network_list = list(network.hosts())

ip_network_list = []
with open ('IP Addresses.txt', 'r') as file:
    ip_network_list = file.readlines()
ip_network_list = [x.strip() for x in ip_network_list]

variable = random.randint(1,20)

interesting_IPs = []
for x in range (0,variable):
    randomly = random.randint(0,len(ip_network_list)-1)
    ipaddr = ipaddress.ip_address(ip_network_list[randomly])
    if ipaddr in network_list and ip_network_list[randomly] not in interesting_IPs:
        network_list.remove(ipaddr)
        ip_network_list.pop(randomly)
        interesting_IPs.append(ipaddr)

with open ('Interesting IPs.txt', 'w') as file:
    print ('The following are the interesting IPs:')
    for x in range (len(interesting_IPs)):
        print (interesting_IPs[x])
        file.write(str(interesting_IPs[x]))
```

Comment: start by simplifying. give us the ip-data in a list and show input and output as it should be.

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to help you because without your input file (`C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\IP Addresses.txt`), we can't be sure your code is doing what's it's supposed to do.

But based on your code provided, here's my attempt:

```
import ipaddress  
import random 
import os

os.chdir('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Desktop/')

network = ipaddress.ip_network('192.0.7.0/24')
network_list = set(network.hosts())

with open ('IP Addresses.txt') as input_file:
    ip_network_list = {x.strip() for x in input_file}

sample_size = random.randint(1, min(20, len(ip_network_list)))
random_networks = {ipaddress.ip_address(x)
                   for x in random.sample(ip_network_list, sample_size)}

interesting_IPs = random_networks & network_list

with open ('Interesting IPs.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_text = "\n".join(str(x) for x in interesting_IPs)
    print ('The following are the interesting IPs:')
    print(output_text)
    output_file.write(output_text)
```

Is is near what you wanted to do?

Comment: Thank you for your help! you did it, subtle change but it really did the trick. Thank you again so much

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to print IPs to the file instead of just to the console. Use the file keyword argument of print.

```
with open ('Interesting IPs.txt', 'w') as file:
    print ('The following are the interesting IPs:')
    for ip in interesting_IPs:
        print(ip)
        print(str(ip), file=file)
```